# Odd behavior of function Fn keys on MSI Creator on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: keyboard, webcam, camera, msi, function-keys

I am currently experiencing problems with the function keys on my MSI Creator 17 B11UG. It has gotten worse and worse with every Ubuntu update (currently 23.04) and I have a particular interest in making the webcam work again, as it is apparently just got stuck in the "hardware disabled state". Some function keys work (mute, volume up/down, keyboard light), some stopped working after the upgrade, some log errors into dmesg, and some work but don't register on `showkey -k`. The detailed table with description how function keys behave currently:

[Fn keys problems description table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCwq6.png)

UPD: *I initially created a markdown table, which looked very nice on the preview, but got scrambled for some reason when I posted, so I created an image instead.*

`showkey -k` detects absolutely the same codes if function keys are pressed alone or together with the Fn key. I also checked the BIOS settings and there isn't any setting which changes the way Fn keys work.

`sudo udevadm info /dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd` gives me this output:

```
P: /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/event3
M: event3
R: 3
U: input
D: c 13:67
N: input/event3
L: 0
S: input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd
E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/event3
E: DEVNAME=/dev/input/event3
E: MAJOR=13
E: MINOR=67
E: SUBSYSTEM=input
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=5374008
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_a0=mute
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_ae=volumedown
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_b0=volumeup
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_b2=www
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_c2=ejectcd
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_df=sleep
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_e2=bluetooth
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_e4=f21
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_ec=email
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_ee=camera
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_f6=wlan
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_f7=brightnessdown
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_f8=brightnessup
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_f9=search
E: ID_INPUT=1
E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
E: ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
E: ID_BUS=i8042
E: ID_SERIAL=noserial
E: ID_PATH=platform-i8042-serio-0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=platform-i8042-serio-0
E: XKBMODEL=pc105
E: XKBLAYOUT=us,ru
E: XKBVARIANT=,
E: XKBOPTIONS=grp:alt_shift_toggle,lv3:ralt_alt,compose:caps,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,grp_led:scroll
E: BACKSPACE=guess
E: LIBINPUT_DEVICE_GROUP=11/1/1:isa0060/serio0
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd
E: TAGS=:power-switch:
E: CURRENT_TAGS=:power-switch:
```

All the diagnostic means (see the table above) seemingly give me contradictory results, e.g. F8 works and changes the keyboard lights, but `showkey` registers nothing and `dmesg` logs an error, some keys generate `Unknown event received`, some `Unknown key pressed`, some both.

`udevadm info` apparently points to the fact that the keyboard was identified incorrectly (as the output contains `E: KEYBOARD_KEY_f9=search` for instance and I don't have that key), so I tried fiddling with `/lib/udev/hwdb.d`:

I edited `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/90-keyboard-ubuntu.hwdb`:

```
# Dell G16 microphone mute
evdev:name:Dell WMI hotkeys:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svnDell*:pnDellG16*:*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_100150=f20

evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svnMicro-Star*:pn*pnCreator17B11UG*:*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_ee=camera                                 # Fn+F6 camera disable
```

Namely, I added the last two lines, everything else was there before. Then I applied the changes: `systemd-hwdb update` and `udevadm trigger --verbose --sysname-match="event*"`. After that nothing seemingly changed in the behavior of the F6 key. I also tried some other random stuff, like changing `camera` to `!camera` or other hex-keys instead of `KEYBOARD_KEY_ee`, but it seemingly changed nothing.

Since neither `showkey -k` nor `dmesg` gave me any indication as to what was the actual hex value of the F6 key, I tried `sudo evtest`:

```
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:  Lid Switch
/dev/input/event1:  Sleep Button
/dev/input/event10: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/dev/input/event11: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8
/dev/input/event12: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9
/dev/input/event13: Video Bus
/dev/input/event14: Video Bus
/dev/input/event15: sof-hda-dsp Mic
/dev/input/event16: sof-hda-dsp Headphone
/dev/input/event17: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/dev/input/event18: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=4
/dev/input/event19: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=5
/dev/input/event2:  Power Button
/dev/input/event3:  AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
/dev/input/event4:  SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
/dev/input/event5:    FX-2
/dev/input/event6:    FX-2 Keyboard
/dev/input/event7:  MSI WMI hotkeys
/dev/input/event8:  gpio-keys
/dev/input/event9:  HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3
Select the device event number [0-19]: 7
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x19 vendor 0x0 product 0x0 version 0x0
Input device name: "MSI WMI hotkeys"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 113 (KEY_MUTE)
    Event code 114 (KEY_VOLUMEDOWN)
    Event code 115 (KEY_VOLUMEUP)
    Event code 148 (KEY_PROG1)
    Event code 149 (KEY_PROG2)
    Event code 224 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN)
    Event code 225 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP)
    Event code 240 (KEY_UNKNOWN)
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
^C
```

It recognized `/dev/input/event7:   MSI WMI hotkeys`, but upon actual testing when I pressed in sequence all function keys (with or without the Fn key) it yielded no output whatsoever. It works with the regular keyboard though.

I would greatly appreciate any advice on how to investigate further or even how to fix the issue. As a workaround I also will be interested in your suggestions as to how can I enable my webcam alternatevely (i.e. imitate pressing Fn + F6 in some other way or maybe something along those lines).

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Creator 17 2020. Ubuntu 22.04:

When I do the `sudo evtest` command, on my MSI, I discovered that

event7: MSI WMI hotkeys - will not show keycodes

event4: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard wil do the trick - will show you key codes